# upgrade symfony from 2.3 to 2.7 issues with form that do not retrieve the entity

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am retrieving the code of an old application that have not been updated for a few years now. Our sysadmin have put the code in a php7 server (it was working correctly on a php5 previously). The code worked quite good. I wanted to make some updates and the first one I did was to upgrade symfony from 2.3 to 2.7.*. And of course, now the problems arise.
I have a form that is correctly rendered (all the fields are OK even the ones from the database). Here is my builer:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('object','text',array(
            "required"=>false,
            "attr"=>array(
                "placeholder"=>"Object"
                )
            ))
        ->add('date','date',array(
            'widget'=>'single_text',
            ))
        ->add('contact', 'entity', array(
            'label'=>'Contact',
            'class'=>'MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact',
            'choice_translation_domain' => true,
            'placeholder'=>'initials',
            'choice_label' => 'initials',
            'multiple'=>true
            ))
        ->add('text','redactor',array(
            "required"=>false,
            "redactor"=>"default"
            ))
    ;
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
public function editMeetingAction($id,Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $meeting = $em->getRepository('MyAPPAppliBundle:Meeting')- 
      >findOneById($id);
    $form   = $this->createForm(new MeetingType, $meeting);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->persist($meeting);
        $em->flush();
        $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('success', 'Meeting 
    edited successfully');
        return $this->redirect($this- 
   >generateUrl('myapp_appli_manage_editmeeting', array("id" => $id)));
    }
    return array(
        "form" => $form->createView(),
        "id" => $id,
    );
}
```

Now when I try to save the form, I have the following error:

[Syntax Error] line 0, col -1: Error: Expected Literal, got end of string.

[1/2] QueryException: SELECT e FROM MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact e WHERE

It seems that the app is not able to retrieve the Contact being selected in the form.
I have no idea what is wrong here as it worked correctly in the previous version. I followed the steps in this website to help me with the migration and modified already some fields in the form (placeholder, choices_as_values etc)
https://gist.github.com/mickaelandrieu/5211d0047e7a6fbff925

It would be much appreciated if you could help me.

[EDIT1]: the form was working properly before I updated symfony from 2.3 to 2.7

[EDIT2]: Entity Contact:

```
<?php

namespace MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

/**
 * Contact
 *
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\ContactRepository")
 */
class Contact
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Email", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="Initials", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $initials;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id_binome", type="integer")
     */
    private $id_binome;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="JobTitles", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $jobtitle;

    /**
     * Tostring method
     *
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set email
     *
     * @param string $email
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->email = $email;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

    /**
     * Set initials
     *
     * @param string $initials
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setInitials($initials)
    {
        $this->initials = $initials;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get initials
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getInitials()
    {
        return $this->initials;
    }

    /**
     * Get id_binome
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getIdBinome()
    {
        return $this->id_binome;
    }

    /**
     * Set id_binome
     *
     * @param integer $id
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setIdBinome($id)
    {
        $this->id_binome = $id;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get jobtitle
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getjobtitle()
    {
        return $this->jobtitle;
    }

    /**
     * Set jobtitle
     *
     * @param string $jobtitle
     * @return Contact
     */
    public function setjobtitle($jobtitle)
    {
        $this->jobtitle = $jobtitle;

        return $this;
    }

}


class ContactRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function findEmailBinome($id_binome)
    {
        $querybuilder = $this->createQueryBuilder("Contact")
            ->select("Contact.email")
            ->where("Contact.id = :idbinome")
            ->setParameter('idbinome',$id_binome)
            ;

        return $querybuilder
            ->getQuery()
            ->getSingleResult()
            ;
    }
}
```

[EDIT getter setter]

```
/**
 * Add contacts
 *
 * @param \MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact $contacts
 * @return Meeting
 */
public function addContact(\MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact $contacts)
{
    $this->contacts[] = $contacts;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove contacts
 *
 * @param \MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact $contacts
 */
public function removeContact(\MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact $contacts)
{
    $this->contacts->removeElement($contacts);
}

/**
 * Get contacts
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getContacts()
{
    return $this->contacts;
}
```

Comment: can you post your entity Contact please

Comment: Sure I have added it.

Comment: can you check if 'myApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact' changing it to MyApp\AppliBundle\Entity\Contact ?

Comment: It is actually MyApp in the code I have and not myApp. I wanted to anonymize a little bit my code. It starts with a capital letter. I have edited my question with that.

Comment: In your browser, press F12 and navigate to the network tab.  Post your form and see what the actual posted value of contact is.  Maybe you did something when you edited the form.  And double check that there is no ContactRepository::find() method that might be doing something funky.

Comment: in the form data I have myapp_applibundle_meeting[contact][]: 138 (it corresponds to the one I have selected before posting). I have a method in the repository but it gets the email of the contact binome. I have edited with the repository

Comment: Just speculating here.  Try restoring your contact type to the 2.3 version.  I don't really know what would cause your query to be truncated.  I am assuming you posted the complete QueryException message.

Comment: No sure how to restore my contact type to 2.3 version? It is indeed the complete QueryException message and it seems indeed truncated!

Comment: Just pull up your original 2.3 code and copy/paste the add('contact'... portion.  I thought maybe the choices_as_values might be causing the issue but if 138 is being posted then that is not the problem.  Might need to use a debugger or maybe start adding some dump statements.  Been a long time since I have had the pleasure of using Symfony 2.x.  I know the leap from 2.7 to 2.8 is surprisingly large but 2.3 to 2.7 should not be a big deal.

Comment: can you just getters and setters for contact in Meetings entity please?

Comment: Same issues when copying/pasting the 2.3 versions. @hoover_D I have added the getters and setters for contact from meeting entity

Comment: It seems that all the "select" calls are beeing truncated. In other forms, if I have to retrieve something from the db, for some reason the query is truncated. Could it be related to doctrine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution. As it was a problem related to the db connection I suspected dotrine/orm to be guilty! I update the composer.json by changing :

```
"doctrine/orm": "=2.2.*"
```

to

```
"doctrine/orm": ">=2.2.3"
```

When I tried composer update doctrine/orm it did not solve the problem. However when I simply tried composer update then my app worked again.
Thanks a lot for your help